# All possible combinations of pandas data frame rows

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a pandas data frame having 4 rows:

df:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A1      A2      A3      A4
B1      B2      B3      B4 
C1      C2      C3      C4
D1      D2      D3      D4
```

How do i find all possible combinations of selecting two rows of this data frame. In this case I can choose 2 rows from 4 rows in 4C2 = 6 possible ways

df1:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A1      A2      A3      A4
B1      B2      B3      B4
```

df2:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A1      A2      A3      A4
C1      C2      C3      C4
```

df3:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A1      A2      A3      A4
D1      D2      D3      D4
```

and so on.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you need to find all the combinations using `itertools`and then use the output of [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) as index to your dataframe. You will get all the possible dataframes of the given number of rows.

```
from itertools import combinations
for index in list(combinations(df.index,2)):
    print(df.loc[index,:])
    print('\n')
```

The output will be:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A1   A2   A3   A4
1   B1   B2   B3   B4


  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A1   A2   A3   A4
2   C1   C2   C3   C4


  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A1   A2   A3   A4
3   D1   D2   D3   D4


  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   B1   B2   B3   B4
2   C1   C2   C3   C4


  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   B1   B2   B3   B4
3   D1   D2   D3   D4


  col1 col2 col3 col4
2   C1   C2   C3   C4
3   D1   D2   D3   D4
```