# How to find combinations between values of two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Source  Target  Value  Source location  Target location
a       b       10     [12.3,1.9]       [13.5,14.3]
c       v       10     [15.3,1.9]       [13.5,94.3]
c       d       18     [1.4,31.9]       [16.6,44.7]
p       q       10     [12.3,1.9]       [13.5,15.3]
x       z        8     [6.3,1.4]        [47.5,4.3]
```

I want to find both the pairs between `Source` and `Target`. I'm expecting my end result to look like this:

```
Source  Target  Value  Source location  Target location
a       b       10     [12.3,1.9]       [13.5,14.3]
b       a        9     [72.9,18.6]       [14.2,31.6]
c       e       18     [1.4,31.9]       [16.6,44.7]
e       c       14     [19.4,5.1]       [12.3,23.4]
z       x        6     [92.3,1.9]       [43.5,14.3]
x       z        8     [6.3,1.4]        [47.5,4.3]
```

As you can see, I want to get both the pairs of `Source` and `Target` - i.e. `a-c` as well as `c-a` as the two rows.

I tried to research on Stackoverflow but it seems like this question hasn't been answered before. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110156/finding-unique-combinations-of-columns-from-a-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count) but they use `groupby` to find the count of columns not rearrange the existing dataframe. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746635/all-possible-combinations-of-pandas-data-frame-rows) one was the closest I got but it returns dataframes on unique combinations of rows not columns. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is:

Define a function to be applied soon:

```
def fn(row):
    r2 = row.copy()
    r2.Source, r2.Target = r2.Target, r2.Source
    r2['Source location'], r2['Target location'] =\
        r2['Target location'], r2['Source location']
    return r2
```

Then run:

```
pd.concat([df, df.apply(fn, axis=1)]).sort_index()
```

This instruction:

- Applies *fn* function to *df*, yielding a "shaddow" DataFrame
  with "pair-reversed" columns

  - *Source* and *Target*,
  - *Source location* and *Target location*,
- Concatenates them.
- Sorts by index.

If you are unhappy about "doubled" index values, add `.reset_index(drop=True)`.