# pandas: calculate overlapping words between rows only if values in another column match

Tags: python, pandas, string-comparison, sentence-similarity

I have a dataframe that looks like the following, but with many rows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'intent':  ['order_food', 'order_food','order_taxi','order_call','order_call','order_taxi'],
'Sent': ['i need hamburger','she wants sushi','i need a cab','call me at 6','she called me','i would like a new taxi' ],
'key_words': [['need','hamburger'], ['want','sushi'],['need','cab'],['call','6'],['call'],['new','taxi']]}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['intent','Sent','key_words'])
```

I have calculated the jaccard similarity using the code below (not my solution):

```
def lexical_overlap(doc1, doc2): 
    words_doc1 = set(doc1) 
    words_doc2 = set(doc2)

    intersection = words_doc1.intersection(words_doc2)


    return intersection
```

and modified the code given by [@Amit Amola](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308769/pandascalculate-jaccard-similarity-for-every-row-based-on-the-value-in-another) to compare overlapping words between every possible two rows and created a dataframe out of it:

```
overlapping_word_list=[]

for val in list(combinations(range(len(data_new)), 2)):
     overlapping_word_list.append(f"the shared keywords between {data_new.iloc[val[0],0]} and {data_new.iloc[val[1],0]} sentences are: {lexical_overlap(data_new.iloc[val[0],1],data_new.iloc[val[1],1])}")
#creating an overlap dataframe
banking_overlapping_words_per_sent = DataFrame(overlapping_word_list,columns=['overlapping_list'])
```

since my dataset is huge, when i run this code to compare all rows, it takes forever. so i would like to instead only compare the sentences which have the same intents and do not compare sentences that have different intents. I am not sure on how to proceed to do only that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you just need to iterate over the unique values in the `intent` column and then use `loc` to grab just the rows that correspond to that. If you have more than two rows you will still need to use `combinations` to get the unique `combinations` between similar intents.

```
from itertools import combinations

for intent in df.intent.unique():
    # loc returns a DataFrame but we need just the column
    rows = df.loc[df.intent == intent, ["Sent"]].Sent.to_list()
    combos = combinations(rows, 2)
    for combo in combos:
        x, y = rows
        overlap = lexical_overlap(x, y)
        print(f"Overlap for ({x}) and ({y}) is {overlap}")

#  Overlap for (i need hamburger) and (she wants sushi) is 46.666666666666664
#  Overlap for (i need a cab) and (i would like a new taxi) is 40.0
#  Overlap for (call me at 6) and (she called me) is 54.54545454545454
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. could you please tell me how i can have the output as something like (e,g the overlap of intent order_call for (call me at 6) and (she called me) is {'call'} based on the key_words column if i change the lexical_overlap function to output the intersection only? thank you very much

Comment: sorry I’m not following your question. your lexical intersection function only outputs the intersection nothing else. as for what you want to print that’s up to you.

Comment: sorry if I am was not clear on my question. so i would like to have an output like the following from your function:
example: the overlap of intent (order_call) for (call me at 6) and (she called me) is {'call'} , and ofcourse for the rest it is an empty set
so I figured that i could make this change in your code:
df.loc[df.intent == intent, ['intent','key_words','Sent']].values.tolist(), but do not know how to proceed to get the output i mentioned above

Comment: the only issue i have is that it does not apply to a situation where there are more instance of an intent

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I figured out what to do to get my desired output mentioned in the comments  based on @gold_cy 's answer:

```
for intent in df.intent.unique():
# loc returns a DataFrame but we need just the column
   rows = df.loc[df.intent == intent,['intent','key_words','Sent']].values.tolist()
   combos = combinations(rows, 2)
   for combo in combos:
       x, y = rows
       overlap = lexical_overlap(x[1], y[1])
       print(f"Overlap of intent ({x[0]}) for ({x[2]}) and ({y[2]}) is {overlap}")
```